# How to override Web and N1QL port on Couchbase Java sdk?

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++

I want to change web and n1ql port at client side. My server's n1ql port is 1919 and web port is 2121 how to override default port numbers?
My connection string is:

```
  Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.fromConnectionString("couchbase://10.10.10.10");
```

I am trying to do like;

```
jdbc:couchbase:Server=10.10.10.10;Web Console Port=2121;N1QL Port=1919
```

Answer (score -1):

From **Custom Port Mapping** in https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/install-ports.html#map-custom-ports

> Most, but not all, port numbers used by Couchbase Server can be
> remapped from their defaults to fit the requirements of your network
> environment.
>
> Changing the port mappings will require a reset and reconfiguration of
> any Couchbase Server node.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.

Comment: if cluster port already 8091  it should recognize. if not try http "http://10.10.10.10:<clusterport>"